# Finding a bound on the norm of a matrix

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, algebra, eigenvalue

first of all I'm sorry but I don't know how to write expressions, so I used images to explain my problem.

I have to find the following parameters: `alpha` and `beta` in order that the following bound holds:

[image]

where the matrix A is the following one

[image]

According to the definition of norm of a matrix, I should find the max eigenvalue of this matrix A.

First of all, I have computed:[image]

Then looking at the solution, I have seen that, the lower 2 × 2 block on the diagonal of this A<sup>T</sup>A matrix has been called B and the maximum eigenvalue of `A`<sup>`T`</sup> `A` is:

[image]

`Question 1: Is the maximum eigenvalue of a matrix always computed in this way? (Cosidering the trace). I usually compute the det(lambda*I-A`<sup>`T`</sup>`A) and then I compute the max eigenvalue`

Then in the solution, there was written: Since we are looking for a bound on the norm of A(q), we can write the chain of inequalities
[image]

`Question 2: Is the bound on the norm of a matrix, always less than the trace of the same matrix?`

`Question 3: I didn't understand from where the highlighted expressions come up. Could anyone help me?`

The final result is the following (but I don't care, I would like to understand the steps):

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: Sorry, Can I put only questions related to programming?

Comment: Yes. Please read what kinds of question are on-topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).